# export const with return value in js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a return value need to get from export const function store in abc.js, it reutrn the value I want successfully, but the problem is when I called this function in another side .vue, it becomes NaN here is code in js.

```
export let auto_quote_no_generator = () => {

  let ans = "";
  let first_half = "Q-CMS";

  const q = firebase.firestore().collection('ALL_quote');
  const snapshot = q.get(); //count is not a function
  firebase.firestore().collection("ALL_quote").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {

    console.log("auto_quote_no_generator1" +querySnapshot.size);
    const docSize = parseFloat(querySnapshot.size);
    console.log("auto_quote_no_generator2" +docSize);

    let addedz = add_zero(docSize);
    ans = first_half + addedz;
    return ans; //<------- the value I want to return
  });
}
```

in my vue file.

```
import { auto_quote_no_generator } from '../firebase';
...

let quote_number = auto_quote_no_generator();
console.log("check quote_num " + quote_number ); // it trun null
```

how can I show `quote_number` successfully?

Comment: Please see [How do I return the response from an aynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/438992), which this duplicates.

Comment: I do not get it, is export const means async?

Comment: No, the Firebase functionality is async.

Comment: I add `let quote_number = await auto_quote_no_generator();` with `async` in function but still not work, nothing from `auto_quote_no_generator()`...

Comment: I'd recommend reading the dupe question and its answers. `auto_quote_no_generator` isn't async and doesn't return a promise; awaiting it does nothing at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

**await** firebase.firestore().collection("ALL_quote")....

const ans = await auto_quote_no_generator();

don't forget the async